# send notification alert when AWS Lambda function has an error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I have a AWS Lambda function running some process in my infrastructure. The Lambda is triggered every 8 hours using a CloudWatch rule. I am trying to raise a notification if any error happens into the Lambda process. I tried to use SES but that service is not available in that Region.

I will like to know any suggestions for this problem:

***How to setup notifications when an error occurs in my Lambda functions ?***

I am looking for suggestions. This questions never asked for doing my task. I will appreciate any official documentation but either way, any help is welcome.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Some suggestions:

**Dead Letter Queues:**

If your error causes failed invocations, you can use a [Lambda Dead Letter Queue](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/dlq.html) to send the event to an SNS topic or an SQS queue.  If you send it to an SNS topic, you can directly [subscribe to the topic](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SubscribeTopic.html) via SNS or Email to get notified any time a message is published to that topic.

**Multi-region SES:**

If you're really set on using SES directly, SES clients can be instantiated with an explicit region provided -- as long as your lambda's execution role has the appropriate permissions, you can send email to SES from a different region. Here's [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html#constructor-property) for instantiating the JS SES Client.

**CloudWatch Logs:**

If your error does not cause the invocation to fail, another option is using a CloudWatch Logs [metric filter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/MonitoringLogData.html) to aggregate failures and potentially alarm on them. If you're using NodeJS, you can simply log out via `console.log()`, `console.error()`, etc. and it will be written out to CWLogs.  More details [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-logging.html).

You can subscribe an SNS topic to CloudWatch Alarms, and notify yourself in the same way as the DLQ.

---

As you gain experience with the error and learn how to process common errors, you could also subscribe another lambda to the SNS topic from the DLQ/CWLogs example to process it as it happens.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I read you answer and I did a search about the metric filter and I created the metric filter but it is raising the notification just one time. I used my email and it sends the notification email error just the first time when the errors happen. I will like to know why is not raising the email more than one. If you have any clue?

Comment: Yes; for a CloudWatch Alarm, if your metric exceeds the alarm threshold in the given alarm period, you'll get a single email noting that the alarm has been tripped.  So if you wrote to the metric 10 times in a single period and the alarm trips for value = 1, you'll get a single alarm notification. If you set your alarm period to something sufficiently low (for your use case of only running once every 8 hours there is no harm in setting the alarm threshold to be very low, like metric value > 1 for 1 period of 5 minutes), you'll see alarms across multiple periods.

Comment: Well, was about time and thresholds. After a few minutes the alarm return to previous state if everything is going well. Thank you

Comment: Relative to the "CloudWatch Logs" option, there is an [ErrorProcessor](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/lambda/latest/dg/sample-errorprocessor.html) example from AWS that you may find it relevant