# Catch Lambda function errors with EventBridge

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I have deployed many Lambda functions in my Serverless Application. So there are plenty of executions and it is hard to track the Lambda errors. My monitoring system is focused to CloudWatch events, but there is no predefined Event with *Lambda status change* detail type.

It is possible to launch CloudWatch events whenever there is a Lambda function error? (i.e: *Timed out* or *Memory exceeded* errors)

Comment: Before trying this may be you can use the filter over the logs...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42627341/send-notification-alert-when-aws-lambda-function-has-an-error

Comment: Best solution in my case was to add a Lambda trigger with an SQS queue that receives Lambda dead letters through an SNS topic.